# Single query "radio button" selection behaviour with UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, sql-update

I am using MS SQL CE 3.5 in an desktop application (Windows Forms C# 4) and is unlikely to change database. I sometimes hit a brick wall in the more limited SQL syntax of Compact Edition.

Currently I need two queries but would like to join them into one:

**UPDATE manganames SET display=0 WHERE id=@id AND display=1**

**UPDATE manganames SET display=1 WHERE id=@id AND name=@name**

display is datatype BIT

Thank you, my question was brief rather than completely clear

Final query follows

**UPDATE manganames
 SET display = CASE WHEN name=@name THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 WHERE id=@id**

PS My stackoverflow formating skills sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something you can try

```
UPDATE manganames
SET display =
    CASE WHEN display = 1 then 0
         WHEN name = @name
         ELSE display
    END
WHERE id = @id
```

There are a couple of conditions that you don't explain.  First, what should happen when display = 1 and name = name?  With what you show, both 0 and 1 would be assigned.  In my example, the first WHEN clause would apply and 0 will be assigned to display.

Second, what should happen when display <> 1 and name <> @name?  In my example, the ELSE condition will assign display to display, which results in no change.